# C++ class with template member variable. and parameter memory out

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, out-of-memory

```
struct PacketBase
{
    virtual ~PacketBase() {}

    template<class T> 
    const T& get() const
    {
        return static_cast<const PacketVal<T>&>(*this).val;
    }

    template<class T> 
    void set(const T& rhs)
    {
        return static_cast<PacketVal<T>>(*this).val = rhs;
    }
};


template <typename T>
struct PacketVal : public PacketBase
{
    T val;

    PacketVal(const T& rhs) : val(rhs) {}
    ~PacketVal() {}
};


class CResponsePacket
{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, const PacketBase*>> m_vPacketData;

public:
    void addValue(int n, const PacketBase& packetData)
    {
        m_vPacketData.emplace_back(std::make_pair(n, &packetData));
    }

    void print()
    {
         for ( auto& data : m_vPacketData )
         {
              std::printf("%d - ", data.first);
              std::printf("%s\n", data.second->get<std::string>().c_str());
         }
    }
};
```

CResponsePacket has template class member-variable.

```
int main()
{
    CResponsePacket packet;
    std::string strAAA("AAA");

    PacketVal<std::string> pVal(strAAA);
    packet.addValue(1, pVal);

    for ( int nIdx = 0; nIdx < 5; ++nIdx )
    {
        PacketVal<std::string> pp(strAAA);
        packet.addValue(nIdx + 1, pp);
    }

    packet.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The result is

1 - AAA
1 -
2 -
3 -
4 -
5 -

Because the instance is in a loop, memory is destroyed. But this is just an example, and I have to use loop actually. How can I solve this...?

......................
..................

Comment: well you can instantiate it on the HEAP using shared pointer, or you can use `std::vector<std::pair<int, PacketBase>> m_vPacketData;` and move the object passed to the vector (if you don't need the pointer, like for polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `std::shared_pointer` or `std::unique_ptr` (depending of your use), and so having the vector looking like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::shared_pointer<PacketBase>>> m_vPacketData;
```

And so then the `addValue` method should look like this:

```
void addValue(int n, const PacketBase& packetData)
{
    m_vPacketData.emplace_back(
        std::make_pair(
             n, 
             std::make_shared<PacketBase>(packetData)
        )
    );
}
```

This will make a copy of `packetData` on the heap, and store the reference in a shared pointer. If you don't what this copy to be made, then you have to define a new constructor in `PacketBase`

```
class PacketBase{
public: 
     PacketBase(PacketBase&& el): attr(std::move(el.attr))... {...}
}
```

and then redefining the `addValue` that accept a rvalue reference

```
void addValue(int n, PacketBase&& packetData)
{
    m_vPacketData.emplace_back(
        std::make_pair(
             n, 
             std::make_shared<PacketBase>(std::move(packetData))
        )
    );
}
```

And then actually calling the right `addValue` from `main`:

```
for ( int nIdx = 0; nIdx < 5; ++nIdx )
{
    PacketVal<std::string> pp(strAAA);
    packet.addValue(nIdx + 1, std::move(pp));
}
```

Or actually just:

```
for ( int nIdx = 0; nIdx < 5; ++nIdx )
    packet.addValue(nIdx + 1, PacketVal<std::string>(strAAA););
```

This will obviously force you to rewrite the entire class, because you are changing the attribute type... the other way that you can achieve this is switch from

```
m_vPacketData.emplace_back(std::make_pair(n, &packetData));
```

to

```
m_vPacketData.emplace_back(std::make_pair(n, new PacketVal(packetData)));
```

But you have then remember to delete the objects on the heap or you will have memory leaks